# If $a_n$ must be all $0$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis

> Show that if a sequence ${a_n}$ satisfies $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{a_nn^k}=0$, for all $k=1,2,...$, then $a_n=0$ for all $n$.

From the series I can only get $\underset{n\rightarrow \infty}{\lim}a_nn^k=0$, $\forall k
$.

I am confused that if $a_n=e^{-n}$, then $\underset{n\rightarrow \infty}{\lim}a_nn^k=0$, $\forall k
$, so maybe there really exists a sequence $a_n$ not all $a_n=0$, s.t. $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{a_nn^k}=0$, $k=1,2,...$.

The $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{a_nn^k}=0$ can be regarded as an inner product of $(a_1,...,a_n,...)$ and $(1^k,2^k,...,n^k,...)$.

I want to use the Hilbert space $l_2$ to solve the question.

As we have $(a_1,...,a_n,...)\in l^2
$, but $(1^k,2^k,...,n^k,...)\notin l^2$, so it's useless.

Thank you for sharing your mind.

Comment: How do you know that the $a$-sequence is $\ell^2$ as well?

Comment: @Semiclassical $a_n=O(n^{-k})$ for all $k$ so $\sum |a_n|^p <\infty$ for all $p>0$

Comment: Perhaps an interesting note is that if infinity is replaced by some $N$, the result would follow from Vandermonde determinant. I'm pretty sure infinite linear systems with coefficients given by Vandermonde matrix have been studied, but it's too late for me at the moment to look up if there are any results that could be applied here.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Please familiarize yourself with complex analysis if necessary...

$\textbf{Preleminaries:}$

For $j \in \mathbb{N}$ set $$g_{j}(z) := \frac{\sin(2 \pi z)}{z-j}.$$

Note that $g_{j}$ has a removable singularity at $z = j$ and we can set $g_{j}(j) = 2 \pi$. Thus $g_{j}$ is an entire function that has a Taylor series centered at $0$ with rapidly decaying coefficients. Set

$$f_{j}(z) = zg_{j}(z).$$

Note that we have $f_{j}(j) = 2 \pi j$ and $f_{j}(n) = 0$ if $n \in \mathbb{Z}\setminus\{j\}.$

Set the Taylor series of $f_{j}$ around $z = 0$ to be

$$f_{j}(z) = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}c_{j,k}z^{k}.$$

Note that the coefficients $c_{j,k}$ rapidly decay to $0$ (faster than any inverse polynomial decay) as $k \rightarrow \infty$ as $f_{j}$ is an entire function.

---

$\textbf{Onto the main question:}$

Note that for all $j \in \mathbb{N}$ we have the following:

$$0 = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}c_{j,k} \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_{n} n^{k}$$

Because of the decay properties of $(c_{j,k})_{k=1}^{\infty}$ we have

$$0 = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}c_{j,k} \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_{n} n^{k} = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_{n}\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}c_{j,k}n^{k} = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_{n}f_{j}(n) = 2 \pi j a_{j}. $$

Thus $a_{j} = 0$ for all $j \in \mathbb{N}.$

Feel free to make the proof more rigorous or to remove complex analysis.

Comment: The idea is brilliant. It doesn't seem hard to justify all the steps.

Comment: Let $b(k)=\sum-{n \ge 1} |a_n|n^k$ which is finite by hypothesis; since the coefficients $c_{j,k}$ behave roughly like $1/j!$ the answer here assumes that $b(k)/k!< \infty$ which is unclear why is obvious and even true; also one can note that $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}|c_{j,k}|n^{k}$ is roughly $e^{n}$ so again the switch of the double series would be allowed if $\sum a_ne^{n}$ converges which is not obvious; while the idea is good, I think the proof is incomplete until one proves that the double series can be legitimately switched